# Videos from Shared Album Not Appearing in iPhoto

Tags: video, photos.app, photo-stream

A friend recently shared an album with me on Photostream. The album contains videos only. I clicked on the invitation and was able to successfully view the videos within the album on my iPhone.

On my Mac however, although the album did appear in the Family and Friends Photos section of iPhoto, it was empty.

This FAQ, https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT20278, states "Can photos and videos be saved or downloaded from a shared album? Yes. After photos are shared, anyone who can view the shared album can download and keep them permanently. Videos can only be downloaded to a Mac or PC."

Based on that, you would think this would work. Any ideas? OSX 10.8.5.

Thanks!

Comment: so just the album is there but nothing inside it ? do you know what kind of video are those (file type)

Comment: What version of iPhoto?

Comment: This is iPhoto '11 (9.4.3) and I was wondering if that was the issue. The album was there, but with nothing inside of it. I do not know the video type, but it was shot with an iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it worked fine after upgrading to Yosemite and Photos 1.0.1. So I'll just chalk it up to the old version of iPhoto.